# Closed unit ball of a closure of convex hull.

Tags: functional-analysis, euclidean-geometry, sequence-of-function

We know that a convex hull is defined as the intersection of all convex sets containing a given subset of Euclidean space, equivalently as the set of all convex combinations of points in the subset. And the closure of a convex hull is the closed set.

So I have taken a subset $Y$ in $c_0$ as $Y=closure\{co\{x_n : n \in N\}\}$, where $(x_n)$ = $(-1/n, 0 ,..., 1/2, 0,...)$, 1/2 in the n-th place. Here, we can see that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly. I understand that Y is a closed set. My problem is finding out the closed unit ball of $Y$, which I cannot define here. Kindly help me.

Note: closed unit ball of a set $Y$ is defined as $B_Y = \{y \in Y : ||y|| \leq 1\}$

Comment: Doesn't every $y \in Y$ satisfy $\|y\|_{c_0} \leq 1$?

Comment: An element in Y will be of the convex combination of $(x_n)'s$. Can you explain your answer? That would be grateful.

Comment: Sure, $B_Y$ is a closed convex set containing all $x_n$'s, hence it cointains the closure of their convex hull.

Comment: In this question, I am stuck on understanding the sequence. If I take the x_1, what will come and so on?  Please help.